# discord.py delete every message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making discord verification bot. I have this now:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def verify(ctx):
    MEMBER = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name= "♰・Member")
    UNVER = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name= "♰・No Verification")
    embed=discord.Embed(title=":oktagon: Verification", description="You are now Verified!", color=0xe67e22)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(MEMBER)
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(UNVER)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    UNVEREFE = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name= "♰・No Verification")
    await ctx.author.add_roles(UNVEREFE)
```

I want him to delete every message and specific delete that verify success message after like 5 seconds. Can i do it somehow? and I also want it to delete every other new message, including that command .verify. Can i somehow do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I do not quite understand what exactly you mean, but there are several ways to delete a message after it has been sent.

First is to use the `delete_after` argument in the `send` function like this:

```py
embed=discord.Embed(title=":oktagon: Verification", description="You are now Verified!", color=0xe67e22)
await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5.0)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send

Secondly you could also delete it manually:

```py
import asyncio

embed=discord.Embed(title=":oktagon: Verification", description="You are now Verified!", color=0xe67e22)
embed_message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
await asyncio.sleep(5)
await embed_message.delete()
```

And if you want to delete the message that invoked the command (aka the `.verify` message), you can use:

```py
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Hope this answers your question.